# define mark up for generic sphinx admonitions with a specific title

Tags: css, python-sphinx, directive, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx to generate HTML documentation for a Python program.

I would like to use the [`generic admonition`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#generic-admonition) directive with a specific title and have it marked up in a way I can define, for example like content generated with the `note` directive, i.e., boxed, but with a different color (most [Admonitions](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives) are not specially styled).

How do I best go about this?

Comment: How about using the [topic directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#topic)?

Comment: @crayzeewulf: no, I semantically want it to be `admonition`; Bud's answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you'd like to apply a custon CSS style to the admonition.  You can do this with a :class: attibute.

For example, the following

```
.. admonition:: my title goes here
   :class: myOwnStyle

   this is the admonition text
```

renders as

```
<div class="myownstyle admonition">
  <p class="first admonition-title">my title goes here</p>
  <p class="last">this is the admonition text</p>
</div>
```

You then add your own style sheet.  For example, by a custom *layout.html* in the _*templates* directory in your *source* directory:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/customstyle.css"] %}
```

Then you can play around with CSS styles in your style sheet using a selector for the *myownstyle* class

Comment: Took me hours to figure this out because I was not phrasing the question correctly to Google. Your answer is thorough and includes more useful information than I thought I could get.

Comment: Good answer. Only thing missing for me is what the css file should look like.

Answer (score 6):

To add css files more easily, put them in the `_static` folder and then add this to `conf.py`:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('custom.css')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example custom.css for overwriting the color of the title and background color of the `myownstyle` admonition.  I used the `app.add_stylesheet()` call in `conf.py`.

```
.rst-content .myownstyle .admonition-title {
   background: #b99976
}

.rst-content .myownstyle {
   background: #e5d3b3
}
```