# Custom colored and numbered admonitions in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm working on creating online notes for a class. I'm using Spinx (reStructuredText). I really want to create some numbered admonitions with a custom coloring scheme (e.g. blue for definitions, green for theorems, orange for examples etc). I'd like to be able to compute something like this:

```
Chapter
=======

.. definition:: My name of choice

   My definition here.
```

And it would render a numbered, custom colored admonition, something like:

## Chapter 1

[image: This is a picture of what I want]

The numbering would take measure of the chapter/subchapter/subsubchapter the admonition is in and (preferably) continue numbering with respect to other kinds of custom admonitions. So if I were to have first a definition and then a theorem in in Chapter 3.2.1 I'd get "3.2.1.1 Definition: My name of choice" and then "3.2.1.2 Theorem: my name of choice".

**Note:**

I have googled everything I can think of, but no no avail. I tried the numbered blocks extension but it didn't really suit my needs. I've tried following instructions on custom admonitions (not numbered though) by creating a `custom.css` add the `def setup(app): app.add_stylesheet('custom.css')` into my `conf.py` file (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162891/define-mark-up-for-generic-sphinx-admonitions-with-a-specific-title)) but I couldn't get it to work. I'm getting pretty desperate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ask one question at a time. Numbering and coloring should probably be two separate questions. If you need help with custom.css, you need to show us what's in it (see also [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom element.

```
|Red-boxts| My Word |boxs| Bla Bla Bla |boxe|


|Green-boxts| My Word |boxs| Bla Bla Bla |boxe|


|Orange-boxts| My Word |boxs| Bla Bla Bla |boxe|


.. |Red-boxts| raw:: html

    <div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; padding: 5px;">
    <h1>

.. |Green-boxts| raw:: html

    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100%; padding: 5px;">
    <h1>
.. |Orange-boxts| raw:: html

    <div style="background-color: orange; width: 100%; padding: 5px;">
    <h1>

.. |boxs| raw:: html

    </h1><p>

.. |boxe| raw:: html

    </p></div>
```

That should show:

[Click to see Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDj6t.png)

Comment: How to achieve this using rst2pdf `pdf_stylesheets` option?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the :class: option of the generic "admonition" directive and custom CSS.

```
.. admonition::  My name of choice
   :class: definition
   
   My definition here
```

allows styling the definition title with e.g.

```
.admonition.definition > .admonition-title {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Numbering of "arbitrary complexitx" can be defined via CSS counters.
(The drawback is, that the numbers are not easily available for references.)